# If $|c_k| \leq k^2 $ does $\sum \frac{(-2)^k +c_k^3}{3^k }$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> If $|c_k| \leq k^2 $ does $\sum \frac{(-2)^k +c_k^3}{3^k }$ converge?

My approach, using the tools that we have learnt so far and trying to be as clear as I possibly can:

If an infinite series converges absolutely, it converges. We will apply the absolute value to the summand and apply the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\frac{(-2)^k +c_k^3}{3^k } \right|=\frac{|(-2)^k +c_k^3|}{3^k } \leq\frac{|(-2)^k| +|c_k^3|}{3^k } = \frac{2^k +|c_k|^3}{3^k } $$ 
Now we can apply our hypothesis that$|c_k| \leq k^2$

$$\frac{2^k +|c_k|^3}{3^k }\leq \frac{2^k +k^6}{3^k } $$
certainly the exponential function grows faster than $k^6$ (this is something we discussed in class and studied)
$$\frac{2^k +k^6}{3^k } \leq \frac{2^k +2^k}{3^k }= 2\frac{2^k}{3^k}=2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k $$
So we can finally conclude that by comparison:
$\sum \left|\frac{(-2)^k +c_k^3}{3^k }\right| \leq \sum 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k  $

The majorant series  is convergent, hence the absolute series is convergent by comparison. Since the series is absolutely convergent, it is also convergent. Conclusion: the series is convergent $\square$

**This feels like a lot of work, I can probably do it in a better way, but this is the first thing that came to mind.**

---

PS: this is the TU Eindhoven 2WA30 midterm practice test of 2014. If any fellow students are practising here. Welcome and good luck! remember, analysis is fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$ \frac{(-2)^k -k^6}{3^k }\le \frac{(-2)^k +c_k^3}{3^k }\le  \frac{(-2)^k +k^6}{3^k }$$

and since the LHS and RHS series converge also the given series converges.

---

The result can be easily shown indeed suppose that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum c_n$  converge and eventually

$$a_n\le b_n \le c_n \implies 0\le b_n-a_n \le c_n-a_n$$

then by comparison also $\sum (b_n-a_n)$ converges but

$$\sum b_n= \sum (a_n+(b_n-a_n)=\sum a_n +\sum (b_n-a_n)$$

and therefore also $\sum b_n$ converges since it is the sum of two convergent series.

Comment: This is basically the same argument as absolute converge, but a bit shorter, right?

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes, I think it is more direect and simpler, if you ar enot aware about that I can add the proof.

Comment: Very neat addition also.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo It is a useful theorem to use which is valid in general also for alternating series. It is like a "squeeze theorem" for series.

Comment: We learnt about the Lebniz test, but I still need some practice with that method. Our professor said this was the way to go for alternating series.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes it is not complicated to learn and use, you only need some practice. Keep also in mind the method here given. Bye